# How to store this option in my SQL Server DB to use in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm trying to figure the best way to store an option column on my DB and insure it doesn't exceed it's range.

My database is SQL Server that will connect to my C# application, this application stores users payroll work-shifts and outputs payslip summaries of total earned for that week/month/2week period. I have 2 columns that I'm not sure how to store:

1st is the option to select weekly/bi-weekly/monthly payslips and the 2nd is to allow users to select a certain shift and store if it was Normal/time-and-half/Double-time their stored hourly rate.

I was thinking of creating application-side C# verification that stops user's inputting incorrect data. Is this the simplest way to do it or is there a best practice for these situations?

Comment: Best practice is to put validation in the database; there are going to be other ways of putting data in the database than your application, and SQL Server has built-in features for enforcing consistency. Use them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use database [check constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) or you could store valid data in another table, which would have relationship to your main table, enforced by a constraint.  You can set relationships up with TSQL or through the 'Database Diagram' tool in SSMS.

Lookup tables are maintainable from your application and would work best where the data is changing.  Check constraints are appropriate when you know every possible value up front.

Here is an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)...

```
USE AdventureWorks ;
GO
CREATE TABLE Person.ContactBackup
(ContactID int) ;
GO
ALTER TABLE Person.ContactBackup
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ContactBacup_Contact FOREIGN KEY (ContactID)
    REFERENCES Person.Contact (ContactID) ;
ALTER TABLE Person.ContactBackup
DROP CONSTRAINT FK_ContactBacup_Contact ;
GO
DROP TABLE Person.ContactBackup ;
```

Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714293/is-it-good-to-use-check-constraints-for-business-rules).